# Custom json on rails 5 api only, using to_json

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on a rails 5 api only. I can get all the data that i want, but i would like to customize the output.I tried some solutions, but couldn't find it yet.

This is my portfolio controller:

```
  def show
    render json: @portfolio.to_json(
      :only => [:title],
      :include => {
        :cryptos => {
          :only => [],  
          :include => [
            {:radarcrypto => { :only => [:ticker, :price] }},
          ]},
        }
      )
  end
```

this is the output

```
{
  title: "Portfolio 1",
  cryptos: [
   {
     radarcrypto: {
         ticker: "BTC",
         price: "190919.85",
    }
 },
  {
     radarcrypto: {
        ticker: "ETH",
        price: "12220.18",
  }
},
],
}
```

But i would like something like that:

```
{
  title: "Portfolio 1",
  cryptos:
    {
     ticker: "BTC",
     price: "190919.85",
    },
    {
     ticker: "ETH",
     price: "12220.18",
    },
}
```

this are my models

```
class Portfolio < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :cryptos
end

class Radarcrypto < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :cryptos
end

class Crypto < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :portfolio
    belongs_to :radarcrypto
end
```

I already tried to use without success:

```
class Radarcrypto < ApplicationRecord
    ApplicationRecord.include_root_in_json = false
end
```

I don't know if there is a better solution to this customization, if would be better to use the views, json.jbuilder for example. thanks.

Comment: There are errors in the JSON object demonstrations. They have extra curly braces. Try putting them through a linter to find the syntax errors and fix them (e.g. https://validatejavascript.com/).

Comment: thanks @H.Almidan , just did the correction, do you know how to get the proper and correct syntax with ruby on rails?

Comment: No problem. Yes, I answered, though it's not in the exact shape that was wanted (a collection of objects separated by commas, not in an array). The answer that I included is also a collection of objects, but each object has a key (that has to be unique). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to include a collection of objects as a value to a key without wrapping them in an array in JSON. ([source (W3Schools)](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_syntax.asp))

It is possible, on the other hand, to have a collection of objects, but each one would have to have its own *unique key*. So the response could be shaped as such:

```json
{
  title: "Portfolio 1",
  cryptos: {
    BTC: {
     ticker: "BTC",
     price: "190919.85",
    },
    ETH: {
     ticker: "ETH",
     price: "12220.18",
    },
}
```

(A different key is going to have to be used if more than one `radarcrypto` can have the same ticker)

I'm not sure how that would be achieved using the `to_json` options (e.g. `include` and `only`). You could probably do it manually by doing:

```rb
def show
  portfolio = {};
  portfolio['title'] = @portfolio.title
  portfolio['cryptos'] = {}
  @portfolio.cryptos.each do |crypto|
    radarcrypto = crypto.radarcrypto
    portfolio['cryptos']["#{radarcrypto.ticker}"] = {
      'ticker': radarcrypto.ticker,
      'price': radarcrypto.price
    }
  end

  render json: portfolio.to_json
end
```

#### Side note

A gem such as [Jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) may be a good candidate if nested shaping of JSON responses is done in multiple controllers.